# how to mention a user

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a report command for my discord bot, so I want it to tell me who is doing the report. In other words, who executed the command. My current code is:

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

    const { User, ClientUser, GuildMember, TeamMember, Message} = require("discord.js");
    
    const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "USER", "REACTION"]});
    
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_SERVER_ID);
    
    module.exports = {

    name: 'report',
    description: "report a naughty person",
    execute(message, args){
    message.channel.send(`@${String(GuildMember.User)} reported:`);
    }}
```

But when you use the command it says:

> @undefined reported:

How do I make it define who it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) to get the user and

```
`${message.author}`
```

to mention them.

```
message.channel.send(`${message.author} reported:`)
```

Comment: I didn't know you can mention somebody with `message.author`. I'm glad I saw your answer, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty simple, you just have to create a new `const`, which will be the following:

```
const author = message.author.tag
```

After that, just replace this statement.

```
message.channel.send(`${author} reported:`);
```

And your code should end up looking like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { User, ClientUser, GuildMember, TeamMember, Message} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "USER", "REACTION"]});
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_SERVER_ID);
const author = message.author.tag

module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    description: "report a naughty person",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(${author} reported:);
    }
}
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: `${message.author.tag}` won't create a mention. It will only display the user's tag. And the `message.channel.send` call in the final code is missing backticks.

Comment: You're right! I misunderstood it and gave him the placement for the tag and not the mention, I also forgot to include the backticks at the end.

Comment: @Rodagave, you can always [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66959551/edit) and fix any issues.

Comment: @Rodagave What Zsolt Meszaros said. No worries. Feel free to improve your answer.